# WiFi stops working when I run tcpdump on wlp2s0

Tags: tcpdump

Very strange thing is happening to me, as soon as I run a simple:

```
$ sudo tcpdump  -c 10 -i wlp2s0 port 22
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

I lose access to the internet (as if I wasn't connected anymore).
In particular, I get this error in Chrome: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET

I have to cut the Wifi off and then back on again to get access to internet again.

Edit1: ping won't work either:

```
~$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

I run Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on a Dell XPS 13